# SAS url work locally but not in production

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have the below code in Python to generate the SAS URLs for my blobs within a specific container.

`

```
def get_signed_url(container, blobPath):
 return generate_blob_sas(
     account_name=azure_account_name,
     account_key=azure_account_key,
     container_name=container,
     blob_name=blobPath,
     permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
     expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1),
     startsOn=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1),
     version='2021-10-04',
     protocol='https'
 )
```

`

I get the below URL
`https://production.blob.core.windows.net/organization-134/2031dfac-0a29-4a73-b344-e5aec4e20282/How_to_send_a_request_in_Postman_1.png?se=2023-12-07T12%3A11%3A46Z&sp=r&spr=https&sv=2023-08-03&sr=b&sig=pPHMDdGqQZUrQ2s3YxLuWhkW%2BaPi1zJvyTSWQX2%2Bx2Y%3D`
Noow, when I am running python locally and get this URL it works fine, however, on production it does not work,  get the below error on the browser:

```
     <Error>
 <div id="in-page-channel-node-id" data-channel-name="in_page_channel__KbVHh"/>
 <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
 <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header      is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:9c8117fc-c01e-0048-4642-28fc5a000000 Time:2023-12-06T12:50:21.7240095Z</Message>
 <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2023-12-07T12:11:46Z /blob/production/organization-134/2031dfac-0a29-4a73-b344-e5aec4e20282/How_to_send_a_request_in_Postman_1.png https 2023-08-03 b </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
```

I have tried to look online everywhere and could not find anything that could help.Some it might be due to time mismatch, since my storage account and python is hosted on azure, I doubt if that is the case

Comment: On production means where you are running the code?

Comment: I have deployed on Azure web apps

Comment: I made a mistake the productinon is not the right account name.

Answer (score 0):

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:9c8117fc-c01e-0048-4642-28fc5a000000Time:2023-12-06T12:50:21.7240095Z Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2023-12-07T12:11:46Z/blob/production/organization-134/2031dfac-0a29-4a73-b344-e5aec4e20282/How_to_send_a_request_in_Postman_1.pnghttps 2023-08-03 b

The above error occurs when you pass the wrong parameters in the **generate_blob_sas** function.

In my environment, when I tried with correct parameters like account-name,account-key,container-name, and blob-name in the **`generate_blob_sas`** function it executed successfully.

**Code:**

```
import datetime
from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions

account_name = 'venkat789'
account_key = 'sxxxxxx'
container_name = 'block-image'
blob_name = 'bike.png'

start_time = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
expiry_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(900))

def get_blob_sas(account_name,account_key, container_name, blob_name):
    sas_blob = generate_blob_sas(account_name=account_name, 
                                container_name=container_name,
                                blob_name=blob_name,
                                account_key=account_key,
                                permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
                                start=start_time,
                                expiry=expiry_time
    )
    return sas_blob
sastoken = get_blob_sas(account_name,account_key, container_name, blob_name)
url = 'https://'+account_name+'.blob.core.windows.net/'+container_name+'/'+blob_name+'?'+sastoken
print(url)
```

**Output:**

```
https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net/block-image/bike.png?st=2023-12-22T08%3A17%3A19Z&se=2023-12-22T08%3A32%3A19Z&sp=r&sv=2023-11-03&sr=b&sig=efXSiJKBqxxxx
```

[image]

When I copied the same blob sas URL and pasted it into the browser it displayed the image successfully.

**Browser:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[azure.storage.blob package | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-generate-blob-sas)